# Is it possible to show fields in sub object (tree based) from JSON file

Tags: json, pivot, webdatarocks

I want to show the fields from JSON objects. Currently, all the fields are loading only from 1st level of the object. Example JSON file is given below.

```
    "DATE": "2021/01/02",
    "VOUCHERNUMBER": "GST/20-21/3833",
    "VOUCHERTYPENAME": "Udaan Sales",
    "INVENTORYENTRIES": [
      {
        "STOCKITEMNAME": [
          "Printed Knitted H/S Tunic BT17 M"
        ],
        "AMOUNT": [
          "703.25",
          "703.25",
          "703.25"
        ],
        
      },
      {
        "STOCKITEMNAME": [
          "Printed Knitted H/S Tunic BT17 L"
        ],
        "RATE": [
          "147.44/Pcs"
        ],
        "AMOUNT": [
          "737.20",
          "737.20",
          "737.20"
        ]
      } ~~~

I want to show ** STOCKITEMNAME** fields. Is it possible?
```

Answer (score 0):

WebDataRocks does not support nested structures in the dataset.
It means you will need to flatten your dataset as shown below:

```
"DATE": "2021/01/02",
"VOUCHERNUMBER": "GST/20-21/3833",
"VOUCHERTYPENAME": "Udaan Sales",
"STOCKITEMNAME": "Printed Knitted H/S Tunic BT17 M",
...
```